# Good documentation/tutorial for python webkit

Tags: python, webkit

I have found links with basic examples of webkit. but could not find any proper webkit class structure documentation on google.

could anyone suggest good links or documentation for webkit?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/ ?

Comment: may be not, I have seen this link It contains good example for beginning with webkit but I am looking for class structured documentation (without example is ok for me) like [gtk.button](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkbutton.html)

Comment: I have found a link from google,
[WebKit](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/index.html), seems to be helpful. Please, suggest other links, if anyone have more information.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It appears that there are multiple Python bindings for WebKit.

For the Qt/KDE bindings, there is a fairly detailed tutorial: http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python/PyKDE_WebKit_Tutorial.

For the GTK bindings, Ars Technica has an example: http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2009/07/how-to-build-a-desktop-wysiwyg-editor-with-webkit-and-html-5.ars.

Answer (score 1):

The PyWebkitGTK api should be mostly the same as the standard GTK api. You can view some documentation built into the webkit, for example:

```
import webkit
print webkit.WebView.__doc__
```

will show signals and properties you can use. You can also use "dir(webkit.WebView)" to show all the methods of the class. You'll see they are very similar to the GTK C [documentation](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html), with some differences, for example, void webkit_web_view_select_all(WebkitWebView) is WebView.select_all in Python.

Answer (score 1):

PySide，a Python binding for Qt.The [PySide.QtWebKit](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/index.html) module has class structured documentation.