# Need help understanding WebKit for python

Tags: python, browser, webkit

today I came across WebKit. And I'm trying to understand what is it? and is it possible to use webkit without gtk? I can't find any information about how to use WebKit. 
So I found this example:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import gtk, webkit

def update(view, frame, resource, request, response):
    url=request.get_uri()
    print url

win=gtk.Window()
win.connect('destroy', lambda w: gtk.main_quit())
win.show()

box1=gtk.HBox()
win.add(box1)

web=webkit.WebView()
web.connect('resource-request-starting', update)
box1.pack_start(web)

web.open('http://python.org')

box1.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Where can I find documentation for `webkit.WebView` or `.open()` method?
Also would like to know is it possible to open the page and than display html code in console? Like I would normally do with urllib2 or mechanize and BeautifulSoup.

Comment: which OS? from where you got webkit module? webkit is a large project which can be compiled to various targets e.g. there is wxWebkit etc

Comment: linux (Ubuntu). apt-get install python-webkit. is that going to help?

Comment: maybe duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535075/good-documentation-tutorial-for-python-webkit

Comment: I'm trying to understand WebKit classes and functions, without gtk

Comment: @Vor: http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/

Comment: @andrean can you post your comment as an answer and I will close the discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the complete api documentation of PySide:

http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/

with a subsection dedicated to webkit only:

http://srinikom.github.com/pyside-docs/PySide/QtWebKit/index.html

That's a temporary mirror, the original was and will be located probably here:

http://pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtWebKit/index.html

And there's PyQt's documentation too, but that's not that much pythonic:

http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/index.html